# wordpress mu domain mapping problem

Tags: wordpress, domain-mapping

i installed WordPress mu and WordPress mu domain mapping plugin but the only problem that i have is that i cant park a domain to use for main domain for example my main domain is foo.com and i want the users to redirect to foo.com by entering bar.com to but after i park bar.com using cpanel it redirects to [foo.com/wp-signup.php?new=bar.com](http://foo.com/wp-signup.php?new=bar.com)

I'm currently using cpanel
+ WordPress network 3.2.1 + WordPress mu domain mapping plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think you may using shared hosting , If yes then you can only do it with your parent domain

Answer (score 0):

Another method may be to simply direct an `A record for bar.com to point to the IP of foo.com web host`.

There is actually no use of Domain Mapping in this case as it is a single site. The domain mapping plugin is made for Wordpress MU (Multiple Users) in mind, ie. different sites on different domains with only 1 wordpress installation on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late reply, but I share the solution with others who have the same problem

This problem might be related to some fields in database, make sure that in the wp_options table, the "option_name" siteurl is set to the right url site, the same for the option_name "home" must be set to the same url site

If the problem is not resolved, then check wp_blogs table, and verify the domain value is well set

Kind regards